# How to stop Weblogic when using domain administration port?

Tags: security, weblogic

I activated domain admin port(9042 in my case) via admin console, no restart needed.
Then I changed stop script:

```
ADMIN_URL="t3s://localhost:9042"
```

I also changed setDomainEnv.sh:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust"
```

But when I run stopWeblogic.sh I get:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://localhost:9042: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: 
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed.; No available router to destination]
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/pi/Programs/Oracle/Middleware/sand_box/domains/prod_basic/shutdown.py", line 3, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 22, in connect
  File "<iostream>", line 648, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running at t3s://localhost:9042 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
```

**What is the proper way of doing this?**

P.D. I also tried with other AdminServer ports 7001 and 7002, but of course it says(as it should):

```
WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has administration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration Port.
```

Comment: 9042 is your "Local Administration Port Override" ?

Comment: Yes it is.Same thing happens when trying from wlst prompt.

Comment: I had this happen to me when I was having other issues with my server (it was throwing a ton of other errors), so the connection to shut it down timed out. You might also try using the IP rather than the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to ask for clarification but I am new and stackoverflow is not allowing me to ask for clarification. Hence I am posting as an answer.

If AdminServer and managed servers share same SSL configuration (like DemoIdentity and DemoTrust) then best practice is to modify setDomainEnv.sh as you have done. If WLS instances on the other hand have different SSL configuration (like DemoIdentity and DemoTrust for AdminServer, and CustomIdentity and JavaStandardTrust for managed servers) then best practice is to modify the stop scripts "DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopWebLogic.sh" and "DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopManagedWebLogic.sh", setting ADMIN_URL to t3s based.

Onto your issue, try following two flags and see if it helps you find the root-cause:

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true
```

These would give you SSL debug entries while WLST session tries to connect to "localhost:9042".

Additionally, if the CN of the DemoIdentity certificate is something other than "localhost" (use command `"keytool -list -v -keystore WL_HOME/server/lib/DemoIdentity.jks"`) , you would also need to set:

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
```